# Get previous year from datetime.date object in python

Tags: python

I know this should be simple, and I know I can do the following:

```
ini_time_for_now = datetime.now()
past_date_before_2yrs = ini_time_for_now - timedelta(days = 730)
```

past_date_before_2yrs: 2017-02-27 12:41:46.104662

But I would prefer to get the previous year from `datetime.date` or something along those lines. As long as I can keep my YYYY-mm-dd format. So here is the question. Is it possible to get the previous year from something like:

```
start_date_object = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

start_date_object from above would be `2020-10-01`

And I want `2019-10-01`

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is `start_date` in your second example? Given that start_date, what would be your expected output when you say 'Get previous year from datetime.date object'?

Comment: @ScootCork Good call. I added more details above. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

does this answer your question

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
last_year = now.year - 1
start_date=f'{last_year} {now.month} {now.day}'
start_date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y %m %d").date()
start_date_object
```

output

```
datetime.date(2019, 12, 1)
```

Comment: This will fail one day every four years.

Comment: @AnonCoward taking in count the amount of all other days, it's a pretty good pass-rate!

Comment: This does not answer my question. I want to get the previous year from `start_date_object` formatted as `strptime(start_date, "%Y %m %d").date()`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
start_date_object.replace(year=start_date_object.year - 1)
```